# How does someone in Australia get access to a list of Politicians meetings?

Tags: australia, procedure

In the report "[Who is in the room? Access and influence in Australian Politics](https://grattan.edu.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/908-Who-s-in-the-room-Access-and-influence-in-Australian-politics.pdf)" the report talks about numbers of meetings with ministers which implies that the list of meetings is somehow accessible.  Additionally, in one of podcasts, they talk about going through spreadsheets of ministers meetings.

My question is how does one get access to these lists of ministers meetings? My assumptions are there is some process to follow but I could not find it by doing a google (or duckduckgo) search.

Answer (score 2):

The sources are listed in the report itself:

> Sources: Grattan analysis of Queensland ministerial diaries (Premier, Deputy
>   Premier and Treasurer), January 2017 to March 2018, and NSW ministerial diaries
>   (Premier, Deputy Premier and Treasurer), July 2016 to September 2017 (Queensland
>   Government (2018) and NSW Government (2018)).

The diaries are available online:

- [Queensland ministerial diaries](https://www.cabinet.qld.gov.au/ministers/diaries.aspx)
- [New South Wales Ministers' Diary Disclosures](https://www.dpc.nsw.gov.au/publications/ministers-diary-disclosures/)

For example [January 2017 ministerial diary of Queensland's Premier](https://www.cabinet.qld.gov.au/ministers/diaries/cabinet-2015-2017/assets/2017/january-2017/annastacia-palaszczuk.pdf)